# iptables FORWARD packets from one chain to another

Tags: linux, iptables

I have 4 Chains in my iptables table - INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD and MYCUSTOM-CHAIN

Now, i have a rule in my INPUT chain that filters all tcp traffic with destination port as 23. I need to re-route all this traffic to MYCUSTOM-CHAIn.

Please let me know if that's possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 23 -j MYCUSTOM-CHAIN
```

Comment: SWEET!! WORKED LIKE A CHARM, I had it almost figured out.. :) Thanks!